# @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) issues after java 8 upgrade

Tags: java, maven, mockito, junit4

My tests are using

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

annotation, which was running well in Java 6, but after upgrading to Java 8, the test started failing with below exception. What is missing here?

I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37  
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
```

Answer (score -2):

Issue is solved, it was not related to mockito. In code one rule was used and was not getting used, That Rule had issues because of which it was giving this error.